# flask - Display database from python to html

Tags: python, html, web, flask, server

I have code like this to retrieve data from database and I want to display it in html.

This is **app.py**

```
@app.route('/news')
def news():
    import pymysql
    import re

    host='localhost'
    user = 'root'
    password = ''
    db = 'skripsi'

    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,user=user,password=password,db=db, use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
        print('+=========================+')
        print('|  CONNECTED TO DATABASE  |')
        print('+=========================+')
     except Exception as e:
        sys.exit('error',e)

     cur = con.cursor()
     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dataset")
     data = cur.fetchall()

     for row in data:
         id_berita = row[0]
         judul = row[1]
         isi = row[2]
         print('===============================================')
         print('BERITA KE', id_berita)
         print('Judul :', judul)
         print('Isi   :', isi)
         print('===============================================')

return render_template('home.html')
```

This is the result

[image]

This is **berita.html**. I want to display inside div class = output

```
<body>
<center>
<header style="padding-top: 10px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 40pt;">WELCOME!</header><br>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="/home">Home
  <a href="/berita">Berita
  <a href="/preprocessing">Pre-Processing
  <a href="/feature">Fitur Ekstraksi
  <a href="/knn">KNN
</div>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass your data using `render_template()` like this:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dataset")
data = cur.fetchall()
render_template('template.html', data=data)
```

Then in your template, iterate over the rows, for example you could render table rows for each row:

```
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi David, could you provide complete code where you pull the data from DB and especially how to push them to html, please?

Answer (score 7):

**render_template** allows you to pass variables to html, and **jinja2** help you to manipulate it. You only need to format your query result and send it within **render_template**

### Example

#### app.py

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_route():
    user_details = {
        'name': 'John',
        'email': 'john@doe.com'
    }

    return render_template('test.html', user=user_details)
```

#### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- use {{}} to access the render_template vars-->
        <p>{{user.name}}</p>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

to make the most of jinja2, take a look at his [Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/)

Comment: But I'll load 1000 datas from database.

Comment: then you need to use some Pagination technique, that's a design issue rather than tech used

Comment: @DavidHerlianto For pagination, you can try and substitute `cur.fetchall()` with `cur.fetchmany(20)` in your code to test what your first page would look like when restricting to 20 items per page. Showing the following pages is then just a matter of passing a parameter for selected page with your request, and scrolling the cursor accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

### Suppose you have table_name = user_info and let's visualize it:

id| name    | email           | phone     |
1 | Eltac   | eltac@gmail.com | +99421112 |

---

You can do something like this:

app_name.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import mysql.connector

mydatabase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost(or any other host)', user = 'name_of_user',
    passwd = 'db_password', database = 'database_name')


mycursor = mydatabase.cursor()

#There you can add home page and others. It is completely depends on you

@app.route('/example.html')
def example():
   mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user_info')
   data = mycursor.fetchall()
   return render_template('example.html', output_data = data)
```

In the above code we use fetchall() method that's why ID is also included automatically

(Header html tag and others are ignored. I write only inside of body)
example.html

```
--snip--

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in output_data %} <-- Using these '{%' and '%}' we can write our python code -->
            <tr>
                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}        <-- Because it is flask framework there would be other keywords like 'endfor'   -->
    </tbody>
</table>

--snip--
```

And finally you get expected result

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't work. Though I did a .fetchone() instead of .fetchall()
But every other thing is the same. BTW, I'm using sqlite